# Gridview.builder not accepting List<widget> in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I can't get a list to be displayed in a Gridview.builder.

```
List<Widget> booksList = [];

return new GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        ),
        itemCount: libraryList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
          return booksList;
          );
        });
```

It returns the error "The return type 'List' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context." and I am stuck on how to proceed.

Comment: you have to return `booksList[index];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Widget> booksList = [
Text('Hello'),
Text('World')];

return GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        ),
        itemCount: libraryList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
          return booksList[index];
          );
        });
```